# Pass an entire yaml from values.yaml to templates in helm

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to pass entire set of yamls from `values.yaml` in helm to the `templates`, so that whatever yaml inputs I pass in the values.yaml section goes in the templates yaml as it is :

For example :

`values.yaml`

```
...
...
metallbConfig: |-
  apiVersion: metallb.io/v1beta2
  kind: BGPPeer
  metadata:
    creationTimestamp: null
    name: peer1
    namespace: metallb-system
  spec:
    holdTime: 3s
    keepaliveTime: 0s
    myASN: 64026
    passwordSecret: {}
    peerASN: 65227
    peerAddress: 10.252.254.194
  status: {}
```

`templates/resources.yaml` :

```
{{ toYaml .Values.metallbConfig }}
```

Essentially what I want to achieve is whole `BGPPeer` section to be present in the `resources.yaml` when I deploy the chart.

Currently I am getting this error :

```
# helm template metallbcnf . --output-dir outputs --debug
...
...
Error: YAML parse error on metallb/templates/resources.yaml: error unmarshaling JSON: while decoding JSON: json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type releaseutil.SimpleHead
helm.go:84: [debug] error unmarshaling JSON: while decoding JSON: json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type releaseutil.SimpleHead
```

Kindly help me resolve the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to embed the yaml entirely, you don't need the `|-`

For example, I have this in `values.yaml`

```yaml
...
probes:
  livenessProbe:
    httpGet:
      path: /ping
      port: 80
    initialDelaySeconds: 15
    periodSeconds: 60
    successThreshold: 1
    timeoutSeconds: 5
    failureThreshold: 3
  readinessProbe:
    httpGet:
      path: /ping
      port: 80
    initialDelaySeconds: 15
    periodSeconds: 60
    successThreshold: 1
    timeoutSeconds: 5
    failureThreshold: 3
...
```

Then use this in my helm deployment:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
...
spec:
  ...
  template:
    ...
    spec:
      ...
      containers:
        - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
          image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag}}"
          imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}

          {{- toYaml .Values.probes | nindent 10 }}
           ...
      ...
```

You'll notice I need to be explicit about the indenting using `nindent` otherwise helm just pastes in the yaml as in the `values.yaml` which breaks the parsing

Comment: Thanks for the response, but this only works when you are aware of the fields in the values.yaml. In my case I can have one or more yaml in the  `metallbConfig` section and therefore need someway to take the entire set of yamls in `values.yaml` and put it in the `resources.yaml`

Comment: As long as it is nested under the first heading (`probes` in my example), it doesn't matter what/how many fields there are -- they will all go into the `toYaml` block

Comment: Oh got it, simply removing the `|-` works  for me, thanks a lot.

Comment: Oh but now, I can't have more than one yaml in the `values.yaml` section.

Comment: How do you mean "I can't have more than one yaml"?

Comment: It means, I can have multiple BGPPeer in the `metallbConfig` in values.yaml, like : 

```
metallbConfig:
  apiVersion: metallb.io/v1beta2
  kind: BGPPeer
  ...
  ---
  apiVersion: metallb.io/v1beta2
  kind: BGPPeer
...
```

Basically, `metallbConfig` is an array of yamls that  we want to deploy.

Comment: You can separate yaml definitions using `---` on its own line

Comment: yup, it fails with below error :

Error: cannot load values.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 350: could not find expected ':'
helm.go:84: [debug] error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 350: could not find expected ':'
cannot load values.yaml

Comment: Can you make your chart available via a repo for others to try to replicate your issue?

Answer (score 0):

values.yaml file contains a string instead of a valid YAML object. You need to convert the string to a YAML object before passing it to the template.

Comment: I believe the purpose of `toYaml` is that only, to convert the string into yaml.

Answer (score 0):

Your string is already syntactically correct YAML (hopefully!) and you can just write it out as-is.  `toYaml` will add additional quoting to turn it into specifically a YAML string and you don't want that.

```
---
{{ .Values.metallbConfig }}
{{/* without toYaml */}}
```

(I'd consider it a little unusual to deposit an entire Kubernetes YAML object in Helm values, especially as an opaque string.  Consider moving this into its own file in the `templates` directory and using templating only for the specific fields that need to be customized.)